# Turtle Library Screen Not Working Properly in Mac but Working in other systems

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I wanted to make a pong game in Python by using the Turtle library, but the output screen is not correct.

[the output screen is like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZbBR.png)

[But it should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J62U.png)

here is my code:-

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong by Sameer")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)

# Paddle B
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(350, 0)

while True:
    wn.update()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Turtle Graphics window shows nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69939334/python-turtle-graphics-window-shows-nothing)

Comment: What Python version are you using?